# Firefox browser loading AngularJS app slowly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, angularjs-material

My Angular JS app is loading slowly on Firefox browser. As a result of this, some of the hidden elements are showing up on the page during page load before getting hidden again. I am using AngularJS material also. I tried moving the script tags to the head. This is fixing the issue in Firefox but in Chrome it is loading slowly. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: for hidden elements, did you try ng-cloak? if you look at the developer tools, you can see that some browser-extensions can increase page load time also... best to compare without any browser extensions in both browsers

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot. Can you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For hidden elements, try ng-cloak

If you look at the developer tools, you can see that some browser-extensions can increase page load time also... best to compare without any browser extensions in both browsers